# Qunit asyncTest that triggers an event passes when run alone but not when run after another test

Tags: jquery, qunit

I've been trying to use qunit to run some tests which require triggering a click then testing if a value was set or divs made visible based on a jQuery function attached to the click event which is in a separate js file. When setting this up I found that any asynchronous tests that run after another test would fail, but would pass when ran alone (or first).

the code below is used for the jsfiddle reduced test case linked at the bottom. The `on('click')` outside of the `test()` mimics the function which reacts to a click and then changes a value. By removing the first `test()` block the `asyncTest()` will pass every time and by moving the `on('click')` inside the `asyncTest()` block the test will also pass every time along side the first `test()` block, so it seems like it's something wrong with triggering external jQuery event from inside a `test()` block and it getting confused when resetting the test code inside the `qunit-fixture` div perhaps.

I've seen a few instances of this type of problem (alternate pass and fail) when searching for an answer, but nothing that seems to explains this particular issue. Can anyone explain why this is happening and perhaps suggest a fix which would keep the functionality set out here if that's possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture">

    <input id="type" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <a id="click">click</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery('#click').on('click', function(){

    jQuery('#type').val(2);
});

test("works", 1, function(){

    ok(jQuery('#type').val() == 1);
});

asyncTest("async", 1, function(){  

    setTimeout(function(){

        equal(jQuery('#type').val(), "2");
        start();
    }, 1000);

    jQuery('#click').trigger('click');
});
```

JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/rFpxL/

UPDATE:

Revisited this and found that by setting my `.on('click')` handler to be delegated it works when the tests are reset, which I think was more the problem, see updated fiddle below.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#click', function(){

    jQuery('#type').val(2);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/rFpxL/4/

UPDATE 2:

I have a feeling that what I was attempting to do here is actually outside of the realms of a unit test and ideally shouldn't be being tested using qUnit and instead should use some other tool for integration testing... or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific test case I could get it to work by making the event handler use delegation.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#click', function(){

    jQuery('#type').val(2);

});
```

I think this is down to when the tests are reset the event binding is lost if not done as a delegation, which would make sense with how jQuery event handlers works.

I'm not entirely sure how this can be used with my actual tests that are run using existing code which I don't want to be changing to be delegated just for testing, but I do at least understand better why the tests are failing.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening:

- The `setTimeout` and `trigger` calls are both asynchronous
- The `qunit-fixture` is not being reset after the test is complete
- The `test` is happening synchronously and blocking the asyncTest

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that's what's happening in this case. I had another look at this and played with my test case to see if there was anything I could come up with and have managed to get it to pass all tests each time by making the `.on('click')` call outside of the tests a delegated event. see updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/rFpxL/4/

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research on this issue as I was having the same problem and found a workaround here: [QUnit how to test events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296959/qunit-how-to-test-events/24343074#24343074)

Woogy managed to get around jquery's behavior of removing event handlers when not delegating by fixing the HTML outside of qunit's fixture. I don't know how feasible this is given your situation, or if you even care anymore, but this worked out well for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for your answer but please not that link only answers are discouraged. At some point in the future, the link may go down and then your answer would be useless. Please consider adding a quick summary of the article you link to and keep the link for further reference.

Comment: thanks for the response, I'll have a look at that post and see if it helps. I think perhaps the problem is more with the usage of qUnit to do integration testing instead of unit testing. Though this is based on my limited knowledge of testing, so I may be talking rubbish.