# QUnit how to test events?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I have an html page with a button like this:

```
<input id='btnSubmit' type='button'/>
```

which triggers a click handler defined within the document.ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: myUrl,
                data: { 'startDate': startDateId, 'endDate': endDateId },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('yay!');
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    LogError(request, startDate, error);
                    location.href = "error/error";
                }
            });
      }
}
```

Now I want to test this functionality with QUnit, so I have built the following unit test in a separate html file that references the .js file containing the code blocks above:

```
QUnit.test("Test", function (assert) {
            var fixture = $("#qunit-fixture");
            fixture.append("<input type='button' id='btnSubmit'/>");
            $("#btnSubmit").trigger("click");
            assert(something);        
});
```

I have numerous other tests within this file that are all executing properly, but whenever I try to create a test that exercises the event handler of an element within the qunit-fixture, it fails to call the actual handler.

I understand that I will need to mock the ajax call to truly test this function. But I first need to determine how to trigger the event. How do I properly trigger and test events with qunit?

Comment: The event handler is added to the button at page load and you are adding a button in your test. I think the event handler is not added to the button added in your test. You may either add the event handler to the button in the unit test or use another tool to test the event handling (like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I ended up just adding the button within the body of the test html document rather than through the qunit-fixture element. Now $("#btnSubmit").trigger("click"); triggers the actual event handler within the JS file under test.  Oh, one other thing I did was mark the button as hidden which isn't necessary, but cleans up the test document.  So the final version looks like this:

**html document to test:**

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
    <input id='btnSubmit' type='button'/>
<...
```

**JavaScript to test:**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: myUrl,
                data: { 'startDate': startDateId, 'endDate': endDateId },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('yeah!');
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    LogError(request, startDate, error);
                    location.href = "error/error";
                }
            });
      }
}
```

**QUnit test file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QUnit Tests</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.14.0.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.14.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
    <input id='btnSubmit' type='button' hidden='hidden'/>
    <script>
QUnit.test("Test", function (assert) {
            $("#btnSubmit").trigger("click");
            //assertions...       
});
```

Comment: I had a similar issue to this, which I found could be resolved by using event delegation `$('#element').on('click', 'a', ...);` which lead me to thinking that the reason that this is that when #qunit-fixture resets for each test, it's removing the elements and replacing them and thus losing the events attached to the elements. This is the same as when you add elements onto a page using jQuery, events aren't attached unless you use event delegation or attached them to the new elements. Hope that makes sense and explains why moving the button outside of #qunit-fixture works

Answer (score 0):

here is list of events present in QUnit and simple implementation

**EVENT** and there     **DESCRIPTION**

1. begin   : Fire when the test suite begins
2. done    : Fire when the test suite ends
3. log     : Fire when an assertion completes
4. moduleDone  : Fire when a module completes
5. moduleStart : Fire when a module start
6. testDone : Fire when a test completes
7. testStart : Fire when a test starts

   ```
   QUnit.begin(function( details ) {
      console.log( "Event for Test Suit Starting." );
   });

   QUnit.done(function( details ) {
     console.log( "Event for Test Suit Ending. Results: Total: ", details.total, " Failed: ", details.failed, " Passed: ", details.passed, " Runtime: ", details.runtime );
   });

   QUnit.log(function( details ) {
    console.log( "Event for Assertion complete. Details: ", details.result, details.message );
   });

   QUnit.moduleStart(function( details ) {
     console.log( "Event for Starting module: ", details.module );
   });

   QUnit.moduleDone(function( details ) {
    console.log( "Event for Finished Running Module: ", details.name, "Failed/total: ", details.failed, details.total );
    });

   QUnit.testStart(function( details ) {
    console.log( "Event for Now Running Test: ", details.module, details.name );
   });

   QUnit.testDone(function( details ) {
    console.log( "Event for Finished Running Test: ", details.module, details.name, "Failed/total: ", details.failed, details.total, details.duration );
   });
   ```